# Scipy: Fitting Data with Two Dimensional Error

Tags: python, scipy

So I already know how to use scipy.optimize.curve_fit for normal fitting needs, but what do I do if both my x data and my y data both have error bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try scipy.odr. It allows to specify weights/errors in both input and response variable.